# SSL connection error facebook

Tags: php, facebook, jquery

"Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error."

i am Creating Fb Apps But Giving This Error.

https://apps.facebook.com/finalyear/

Comment: Do you have SSL set up on your application server?  What do your application settings look like on fb?

Comment: no i not!! i have no idea about SSl??

Comment: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=ikirsha.com

Comment: I believe last year, Facebook started requiring SSL, you can create a self signed cert fairly easily depending on what you are using to serve content.  For instance, [Guide for Apache](http://www.positivessl.com/ssl-certificate-support/guides/ssl-certificate-securing_apache.html)

Answer (score 1):

`Error 107: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` means that you do not have SSL enabled on your server or for your domain. If you do not know how to enabled SSL, then I recommend contacting your server company and asking them to enable it for you, as the complexity varies with each server interface, location.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is required for all Facebook Tab and Canvas applications at this point.

You've entered https://ikirsha.com/fyp/reg/ as your URL but that URL is non-functional, because your server doesn't have SSL turned on. You'll need to get an SSL certificate for it and have your host install it.